# PyOpenGL show texture in shader

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, pyopengl

I'm totally new to PyOpenGL and trying to add a shader to live camera footage.

The footage is being displayed correctly, and the shader (commented out because there's nothing in it yet) is working too.

The thing is i don't know how to display the camera texture inside the fragment shader. Can someone help?

initialization:

```py
def init():
    #glclearcolor (r, g, b, alpha)
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape)
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard)
    glutIdleFunc(idle)

    fragmentShader = compileShader(getFileContent("shader.frag"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    global shaderProgram
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram)

    #glUseProgram(shaderProgram) SHADER HAS NOTHING IN IT
```

**repeats every frame**

```
def idle():
    # capture next frame
    global capture
    _, image = capture.read()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.flip(image, -1)

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_RGB,
                 1280, 720,
                 0,
                 GL_RGB,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 image)
    cv2.imshow('frame', image)
    glutPostRedisplay()
```

```
def display():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    
    # this one is necessary with texture2d for some reason
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    # Set Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    # Switch to Model View Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    # Draw textured Quads
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex2f(width, 0.0)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
    glVertex2f(width, height)
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0, height)
    glEnd()
    glFlush()
    glutSwapBuffers()
```

Comment: *"[...] I don't know how to display the camera texture inside the fragment shader [...]"* - so where is your fragment shader?

Comment: its in another file, shader.frag here is it:#version 120

void main()
{
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note first that you are using a deprecated OpenGL and GLSL version as well as outdated technologies. Read a tutorial (e.g. [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures)) for a state-of-the-art implementation.

---

Add a texture [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)) [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable to the shader. The binding via the texture object and the sampler takes place via the texture unit. Since the texture object is bound to texture unit 0 ([`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml)), you don't need to set the sampler at all, as its default value is 0. However you can set it with [`glUniform1f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml).
Use the [`texture2d`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml) function to texels from a texture (see also [Combine Texture + Fragment](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-12-tutorial/combine-texture-fragment/))

Vertex shader

```c
void main()
{
    // [...]

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

    // [...]
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    // [...]

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

Fragment shader